# align fixed width child-elements centrally in unknown-width parent-container

Tags: html, css

Hi HTML/CSS Developers ! 
Stuck in a strange scenario 
will try to explain my query through images.
Need it to work in IE 8 or 9 atleast.

**Points:**
its an approach for a responsive layout,

```
.container {width:100%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block;}
.parent-container {width:auto;overflow:hidden;margin:0 auto;display:block}
.child-element {width: 285px;float:left
}
```

**Hierarchy**
.container > .parent-container > .child-element

**Labels:**
 I have a 100% container

inside it, I have a parent-container {no width-declared (red background color)}
inside that i have child-elements with a fixed width.

What I want that, no matter, what my screen size is, if there is space for 3 child or 4-child elements, my parent element should always be in center.

*width of child elements should contribute to parent-elements width*

**This is what i have**

[image: This is what I have]

**This is what i am getting**
[image: This is what I'm getting]

**This is what i want it to be (see the parent-width is reduced depending upon child-element)**
[image: This is what I need]

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/happy2deepak/9wm7ppwL/2/

Comment: Please add your HTML too.

Comment: ok.. adding fiddle in a while

Comment: @happy2deepak I think you'll need some javascript for that.

Answer (score 1):

You need some javascript to update the parent container's width according to the window width, you can do it by dividing window width by child width (padding and margin included) and take the maximum possible children which is the floor of the division result

```
function setContainerWidth(){
    var childWidth = 305, 
        winWidth = $(window).width(), 
        parentContainer = $('body').find('.parent-container'), 
        minChildren,
        containerCalculatedWidth;

        minChildren = Math.floor(winWidth / childWidth);
        parentContainer.css("width", minChildren * childWidth);
}

setContainerWidth();

$(window).resize(setContainerWidth);
```

a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ya1kscaq/) to see how it works.

Comment: Ya, even I had to do to with javascript, but I'm looking for some pure css and html way. Still, thanx

Comment: So may be you can try to fix it using some css media queries [responsive design](http://www.toptal.com/front-end/introduction-to-responsive-web-design-pseudo-elements-media-queries)

Comment: Ya, but there is no max-width limit ! Even if I set it for say 1200px or 1400px, but what if screens are much bigger.?.. I can't wrap it inside a 1200px parent-container for screens with > 1900px width or more